# How to debug windows store app crashes?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, uwp

The Windows Dev Center Dashboard shows me crash reports. However, I, as a managed code programmer, don't know how to read them. In fact, this doesn't seem to make much sense - these errors shouldn't be happening in managed code, even if it is compiled into native code. Like, for example, `INVALID_POINTER_READ` - that shouldn't be happening in code written exclusively in C# without any `unsafe` parts.

So what's the explanation of this? Or where is there documentation for this?

Comment: who developed the code that is being used in your store app..? do you have access to the source code..? also it's going to be rather difficult for anyone in my opinion to know what the error message pertains to without seeing if your app is using `Managed or UnManaged` code..

Comment: I developed it. And as I've said - managed only. And I'm not asking for help with this error, of course. And.......

Comment: if you are managing this only what makes you think that someone can accurately answer this without being able to see how resources are being consumed, created and or managed.. this is to broad in nature in my opinion perhaps you can check this out for some possibilities and or possible reasons why - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540582(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Have you read [Debugging a Windows 8.1 Store App Crash Dump](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2014/01/13/debugging-a-windows-8-1-store-app-crash-dump.aspx)?

Comment: @ClayVerValen Thanks. I'm looking at it now. But I'm not expecting too much as it says there `In CLR languages, errors are modeled as exceptions and are represented as class objects derived from System.Exception.` - not the case here. (Perhaps because the CLR is not involved in UWP apps as opposed to the linked article which talks about Windows 8.)

Comment: I believe you might be mis-reading that section.  Because of the specifics of how a language presents errors (e.g. JavaScript =>  JavaScript Exception (JSE) objects, C# => objects derived from System.Exception), a least common denominator approach of sending a HRESULT (Error Code) and a HSTRING (Error Message) through the projection layer is used.  If you examine the [2nd image](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-77-00-metablogapi/3660.image002_5F00_14459429.jpg) in that article you'll see the CLR is definitely there.

Comment: @ClayVerValen Exactly. While UWP apps are compiled into native code. 'There _is_ no CLR'.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to look at this link ? Maybe it'll help you:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephe/archive/2015/03/30/how-to-make-use-of-crash-dumps-available-on-the-store-dev-portal.aspx

Thanks,

Comment: This is link for Windows Phone dev center which doesn't exist any more.